# Not sure if this is fully refundable or if this is a play on words?

Tags: tickets, cancellations

I want to purchase a refundable ticket as I am likely cancel it in the future. The information given by them is confusing, probably on purpose, it could also be my lack of experience.

They mention that the ticket is fully refundable, but also a cancellation fee and a note saying "Cancellations not allowed"

[image]

Can someone explain please?
Thanks

If the question is too easy, please let me know in the comments before flagging it as inappropriate. Thanks

Comment: Actually that really is confusing!

Comment: It looks like this message is generated by Expedia rather than by the airline itself.  If you try to book the same ticket through the airline directly, you may be able to get a clearer explanation of the policies.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes that's right, this was through Expedia. To book the ticket through the airline I have to call the airline which is why I chose to do it through Expedia.

Comment: The cancellations not allowed restriction is confusing. The cancellation fee makes more sense because the rule in the message says ‘tickets are refundable’ (not ‘fully refundable’).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be reliably answered by Expedia and/or the airline.